# Como utilizar el operador LIKE

Tags: c#, sql

tengo esta sentencia en c# para realizar una busqueda parametrizada o filtrada utilizando el like.

```
    else if(rbnombre.Checked==true)
        {
            try
            {
                if (txtbusqueda.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Debe de llenar el campo de filtro para realizar la busqueda", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    txtbusqueda.Focus();
                }
                else
                {

                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand consulta = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Usuarios NOMBRE LIKE '%" + txtbusqueda.Text + "%'", con);
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(consulta);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    dtgv.DataSource = dt;


                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("La consulta no arrojo resultados" + ex, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
```

> me arroja este error: incorrect syntax near de keyword 'like'

Comment: pues porque te falta un `WHERE`: `FROM Usuarios WHERE NOMBRE LIKE '%......`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Además de faltarte la cláusula `WHERE`, es recomendable que cambies esa forma de hacer consultas, ya que es propensa a ataques por [inyección de SQL](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

Lo que te recomiendo es que hagas la consulta así, haciendo además uso de [bloques `using`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement):

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    string Comando = "SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE Nombre LIKE @query";
    using (SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand(Comando, con)
    {
        cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmnd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() {
                                ParameterName = "@query",
                                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                                Value = string.Format("%{0}%", txtbusqueda.Text)
                            });

        con.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader dataReader = cmnd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(consulta);
            dataReader.Dispose();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dtgv.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un error en la sentencia SQL:

```
 SqlCommand consulta = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE NOMBRE LIKE '%" + txtbusqueda.Text + "%'", con);
```

Answer (score 1):

Te falto agregarle la clausa WHERE:

```
SqlCommand consulta = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE NOMBRE LIKE '%" + txtbusqueda.Text + "%'", con);
```

Por cierto, tu codigo esta muy propenso a injecciones sql. Te aconsejo que hagas una [consulta parametrizada](https://www.webprogramacion.com/12/adonet/consulta-de-actualizacion-sql-con-parametros.aspx).